# Set default "reaction time" when interval is not broken jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, timing

I'm stuck with this one and hope that anyone can help me.

The script picks a word and records the elapsed time (reaction time) between word appearance and keypress.  My idea was to have one function that picks the word, set it as interval, and have this interval broken by keypress. The attributes "stim" and "type" are for further use and I got problems if I had them picked more than once.

Here it is on fiddle: [Fiddle of my problem](http://jsfiddle.net/vddnd/)

It does not, however, work quite correct. The default reaction time (2000ms), should only be recorded when there is no keypress. But as it is now, its recorded each time.

Js code:

```
var teststim = [{
    stim: "A",
    type: "letter"
}, {
    stim: "B",
    type: "letter"
}, {
    stim: "1",
    type: "integer"
}, {
    stim: "2",
    type: "integer"
}];
var RT = [];
var Type = [];
var Stim = [];
var displayword = function () {
    stuff = teststim[Math.floor((Math.random() * teststim.length))];
    $("#present").fadeOut(1000, function () {
        $("#present").text(stuff.stim).fadeIn();
        t1 = (new Date()).getTime();
    });
    reac = 2000;
};
timing = setInterval(displayword, 2000);
$(document).keypress(function (e) {
    clearInterval(timing);
    var t2 = (new Date()).getTime();
    reac = t2 - t1;
    t1 = t2;
    timing = setInterval(displayword, 2000);
});
```

Comment: I intended the clearInterval to prevent reac = 2000 and to make it reac = t1-t2. In other words, this is my way to deal with the default reaction time and it's not working.

Comment: From what I see it counts time correctly on button press and resets the timer for default reaction, so if you push a button in 123ms and then wait 2s, youll get: [123, 2000]. If you pushed another button now before fade you'll get like [2200] because timer doesn't reset until it fades. So what exactly is not working?

Comment: But the problem is that there is always a 2000ms between, say, the second and third stimulus, even if I pressed a key. Before I could react with a proper keypress, it already records the 2000ms. If you react on each stimulus with a keypress, there should never be a 2000ms reaction time.

Comment: In other words, the problem is that it records 2000ms as soon as the word is shown, before you can in fact enter anything. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, your mistake is here:

```
    reac = 2000; RT.push(reac); $("#RT").val(RT);
```

You push and show reaction time as soon as you show word to type.

[Here is your fiddle fixed](http://jsfiddle.net/vddnd/1/).

Key is to first show the word and then start counting and not do it concurrently.

By the way there is still a little problem with reseting t1 in wrong place, so if you hit the keypress before fadeOut, but after default reaction time has fired, you'll get result like "2200".

You can fix it by, for example, putting it out of fadeOut: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vddnd/2/)

To make it also change every time you press a key you can modify it like that: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vddnd/3/)

Comment: Thank you for the edits. In your last fiddle, if I press a key it records nicely, but if I then wait for the next stimulus, it has still the 2000 and it waits longer to present the next one. I want to keep the presentation routine with just the two options: default time and time after keypress. Do you have an idea how to implement in your last fiddle?

Comment: The timer is reset to 2000 every time you press the key. Do you want it to behave differently? Or do you mean that the word should be changed after maximum 2000 (since now it changes after X+2000 and in fact can be rendered indefinitely if you keep pressing buttons). If so, then should it be changed after every keypress or always after 2000?

Comment: I've edited it so it changes after keypress. Take in consideration that it "lies" a bit, since it starts counting before you can actually see the word (because of fadeIn/fadeOut animation).

Comment: Awesome! And do you by any chance know how much it "lies"? I could then correct for that. I saw you set the fadeIn and fadeOut to 200, how long is the word visible then? Is it 200+200=400ms?

Comment: Well, yeah, around that, but people are tricky and can start guessing before the animation ia fully complete etc ;)

Comment: And could I change the fadeIn/fadeOut so that it is invisible for exactly 500ms and visible for 1500ms?

Comment: What about using hide/show instead of fadeIn and fadeOut? The last two fade in and out, meaning they get more and more (or less and less) visibile with every milisecond, so you won't ever be able to tell whether it's already guessable or not (or you can make the animation quick and approximate the precision)